# How can we display Japanese (Hiragana) on our website?

Tags: html, iis-7, coldfusion, windows-server-2008, sql-server-2012

We are hosting a contest on our site that is open to the international community. A small percentage of our users are Japanese and have asked to be able to post comments on our site using Hiragana.

Currently, their comments show up as strings of ?????? question marks.

We are using a Win 2008 server running IIS 7 and Coldfusion 10. The DB where the comments are stored (and also appear as ?????? question marks) is SQL Server 2012.

The site is currently using the UTF-8 charset:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Not sure where I need to make changes.  DB? CF? Windows? IIS? Website code? Any ideas?

I've found other similar questions, but they usually have to do specifically with WordPress, Joomla, or site's that are entirely Japanese.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to make sure your database is using UTF-8 encoding as well. Check the documentation on collation and character encoding here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You might claim you are using UTF-8, but are you really? If your database, strings (the programming language might need to be told to handle strings as UTF-8), and actual output encoding aren't UTF-8, then you won't get proper results.

Then here is the font issue; many characters are not included in every font and thus don't work on a lot of computers.

Also try setting headers like this as actual headers.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but what do you mean "try setting headers like this as actual headers?"

Comment: Nick, he means setting actual HTTP headers, using [cfheader](http://cfdocs.org/cfheader).

Answer (score 0):

collation has nothing to do with this  neither do fonts (your unicode data is getting garbaged going into the db). so...

you should be talking to your db via one of the JDBC drivers not ODBC.

your db should be unicode capable & you must use unicode capable datatypes to hold the data (eg, for sql server use the "N" datatypes like Nvarchar, etc).

i assume you're using cfqueryparam (its a user facing form after all), so you need to enable the "Enable High ASCII characters"... option for that datasource in cfadmin (under the advanced menu).

Comment: Are there drawbacks to Enabling High ASCII characters? For example, would we get errors if someone tried entering a Japanese character into a varchar field, or would it still deprecate to a question mark? I can change my DB table and queries to use nvarchar instead of varchar for this form, but I don't want to break something else as a result of making the change in the CF Admin.

Comment: Also, our SQL Server instance is using the SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation. I'm reading that there isn't a UTF-8 collation for SQL Server, but it sounds like that's not an issue if we use the "n" data types (e.g. nchar, nvarchar, etc.).  Is that correct?

Comment: no, it only affects cfqueryparam use & then only to allow unicode. you can also use SQL hinting in your cfquery change 'text' to **N**'text but i would not recommend doing that as cfqueryparam is best practice for user facing form data.

collation has no effect on data entry, only on sorting. its been awhile since i mixed codepoints but i think those japanese language entries will sort to the end.